# Make Outliers same color as boxes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have yet to find any solution on the net for list after a few hours.  I want the outliers to be the same color as the boxes.

```
outlier.colour = NULL
```

Does not work.  Here is code.  This should be as easy as passing a par statement with the outcol and outbg parameters.  I also saw a post to add the same argument for "scale_colour_manual with same colors but this doesn't work either.

```
library(datasets)
t <- ggplot(airquality, aes(factor(Month), Ozone))
t +  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Month)), outlier.size = 2, outlier.color = NULL) +
        scale_fill_manual(name = "Ozone Levels Per Month", values = c("pink", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outliers inherit the color of the lines and not the fill color.

```
t +  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Month), color = factor(Month)), outlier.size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Ozone Levels Per Month", values = c("pink", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Ozone Levels Per Month", values = c("pink", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Month)), outlier.size = 2, outlier.colour = NA) #if you want grey lines
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works for me.  I guess all the "documentation" also forgot to indicate that outlier.colour needs to = NA and not = NULL.  If you enter NULL it doesn't work.  Thanks for the details.

Comment: NA simply doesn't print the outliers.